# EF Core filter the child entities after include

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am working with EF Core and I created a generic repository. I have a method which returns all the entities with their child entities. Here is my method:

```
public Repository(DevbAERPContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        Table = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllWithInclude(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string[] includeProperties)
    {
        var result = includeProperties.Aggregate(Table.Where(where), (query, path) => query.Include(path)).AsNoTracking();
        return await result.ToListAsync();
    }
```

While using this method I don't want to get the soft deleted data. I can filter the parent entity by writing where expression but I also want to do the same for the child entities. Currently I can handle the issue in controller like this:

```
var roles = await _roleRepository.GetAllWithInclude(x => !x.IsDeleted, new string[] { "RoleTemplateSkills", "RoleTemplateSkills.Skill" }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var mappedRoles = _mapper.Map<List<RoleTemplateViewModel>>(roles);
        foreach(var mappedRole in mappedRoles)
        {
            mappedRole.RoleTemplateSkills = mappedRole.RoleTemplateSkills.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
        }
```

What I want is to do this filtering in my generic repository method. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem exactly. But here below is a sample code I used in one generic repository may help you.

```
public TEntity FindByInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> result = dbSet.Where(predicate);


            if (includeProperties.Any())
            {
                foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
                {
                    result = result.Include(includeProperty);
                }
            }

            var firstResult = result.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

            if (firstResult != null)
                dbSet.Attach(firstResult);

            return firstResult;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> result = dbSet.AsNoTracking();

            return includeProperties.Aggregate(result, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
```

However, In the constructor, I didn't use Table. Instead I used as the following

```
public class FitnessRepository<TEntity> : IFitnessRepository<TEntity> where TEntity :class {
    private readonly FitnessDbContextt fitnessDbContext;

    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public FitnessRepository (FitnessDbContextt context) {
        fitnessDbContext = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<TEntity> ();

    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a filter to the Entity it self in the Entity designer? so you can skip adding the condition here.

Thanks

[image: Adding condition to the entity]